# Custard surface has tiny pockmarks when I use fruit pulp

Tags: custard

I have a custard recipe that I use for creme caramel (milk, eggs, sugar, salt). I have made thousands of creme caramels using this recipe. I use vanilla a lot but also use chocolate, coffee etc. When I try to use fruit pulp in the custard, the texture looks like it has small pockmarks across it - see pic). Even if I only use pulp weighing 10% of the whole recipe. I know I could get around this with extracts but I would rather use fruit puree if I can.

I have tried using a water bath and a steamer with the same result. I have tried blending the fruit into a puree prior to cooking, dissolving whole segments of fruit in cream as it warms, pushing pulp through a sieve prior to cooking, straining through cloth after cooking. The pock marks persist. Is there anything that can be done to smooth the surface out? The custards taste great, but I'm used to them looking flawless too. It has only ever happened when I use fruit puree. Love to hear suggestions.

[image: Custard issue]

Answer (score 3):

The acid in the fruit is denaturing the egg proteins, creating this texture.

You cannot reuse the same ratios and temperatures for simple custard and for fruit custard. Find a different recipe which is explicitly made to work with fruit.